# SASS @each skip specific line(s) if variable exists

Tags: css, sass

I'm attempting to build a grid system using SASS and so far so good however if the breakpoint is 'xs' I'd like to skip the `@media #{$query} {` and `}` line for this as the xs no longer needs a media query.

Can anyone advise?

```
$default__gridColumns: 18;
$default__flexColumns: 12;
$default__gutter: 20px;

$default__breakpoints: (
    'xs': 'screen and (max-width: 767px)',
    'sm': 'screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px)',
    'md': 'screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1200px)',
    'lg': 'screen and (min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1440px)'
);

.flex {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 -$default__gutter;
    padding: 0 $default__gutter;
    > *[class^="span__"] {
        padding: 0 $default__gutter;
        position: relative;
    }
    @each $breakpoint, $query in $default__breakpoints {

        @media #{$query} {

            @for $i from 1 through $default__flexColumns {
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--#{$i} {
                    width: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--offsetLeft-#{$i} {
                    margin-left: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--offsetRight-#{$i} {
                    margin-right: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--push-#{$i} {
                    left: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--pull-#{$i} {
                    right: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .visible__#{$breakpoint} {
                    display: block !important;
                }
                > .visible__#{$breakpoint}--flex {
                    display: flex !important;
                }
                > .visible__#{$breakpoint}--inline {
                    display: inline !important;
                }
                > .visible__#{$breakpoint}--inlineBlock {
                    display: inline-block !important;
                }
                > .hidden__#{$breakpoint}--inlineBlock {
                    display: none !important;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to use a `@mixin`.

You can use an `@if` directive to test the value of the `$breakpoint`:

```
$default__gridColumns: 18;
$default__flexColumns: 12;
$default__gutter: 20px;

$default__breakpoints: (
    'xs': 'screen and (max-width: 767px)',
    'sm': 'screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px)',
    'md': 'screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1200px)',
    'lg': 'screen and (min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1440px)'
);

@mixin flex_column( $breakpoint ) {
  @for $i from 1 through $default__flexColumns {
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--#{$i} {
                    width: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--offsetLeft-#{$i} {
                    margin-left: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--offsetRight-#{$i} {
                    margin-right: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--push-#{$i} {
                    left: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .span__#{$breakpoint}--pull-#{$i} {
                    right: $i/$default__flexColumns * 100%;
                }
                > .visible__#{$breakpoint} {
                    display: block !important;
                }
                > .visible__#{$breakpoint}--flex {
                    display: flex !important;
                }
                > .visible__#{$breakpoint}--inline {
                    display: inline !important;
                }
                > .visible__#{$breakpoint}--inlineBlock {
                    display: inline-block !important;
                }
                > .hidden__#{$breakpoint}--inlineBlock {
                    display: none !important;
                }
            }
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 -$default__gutter;
    padding: 0 $default__gutter;
    > *[class^="span__"] {
        padding: 0 $default__gutter;
        position: relative;
    }
    @each $breakpoint, $query in $default__breakpoints {

        @if $breakpoint == xs {
          @include flex_column( #{$breakpoint} )
        } @else {

        @media #{$query} {
          @include flex_column( #{$breakpoint} )
        }
    }
    }
}
```

There's not really a way to skip just the lines you want because of how the CSS will compile with the brackets present in the `@media` query var.

Comment: Much appreciated reply. I’m trying not to duplicate any code so wondering if there’s another way round this...

Comment: I don't think there is, mainly because of the `{}` for the `@media` query var and the opening `{` for the media query as well. Escaping that character doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @JohnthePainter I added a `@mixin` so you can avoid duplication of code.

Comment: Awesome! glad I could help. You can test it out at https://www.sassmeister.com/ just to make sure (I did :). Please mark this as accepted (if you feel it meets all requirements). I think this will definitely help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map-remove`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/map#map-remove)

```
$default__breakpoints: (
    'xs': 'screen and (max-width: 767px)',
    'sm': 'screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px)',
    'md': 'screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1200px)',
    'lg': 'screen and (min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1440px)'
);

.flex {
    // ...
    $custom_breakpoints: map-remove($default__breakpoints, 'xs');
    @each $breakpoint, $query in $custom_breakpoints {
        @media #{$query} {
            // code
        }
    }
}
```

It returns a copy of the map so you don't have to worry about it being removed from your `$default__breakpoints` variable.

---

**EDIT:** I misunderstood your question. You could do that with [`@at-root`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root) although that does add one extra indent:

```
$default__breakpoints: (
    'xs': 'screen and (max-width: 767px)',
    'sm': 'screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px)',
    'md': 'screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1200px)',
    'lg': 'screen and (min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1440px)'
);

.flex {
  // ...
  @each $breakpoint, $query in $default__breakpoints {
    @media #{$query} {
      @at-root (with: if($breakpoint == 'xs', rule, all)) {
        .selector {
          content: 'value';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will compile to

```
.flex .selector {
  content: "value";
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px) {
  .flex .selector {
    content: "value";
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1200px) {
  .flex .selector {
    content: "value";
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1440px) {
  .flex .selector {
    content: "value";
  }
}
```

Comment: This is nice but I do need to include it in the loop, I just don't want it to include the @media part for 'xs' only.

Comment: @JohnthePainter my bad, I misunderstood what you needed. Added an extra option to my answer.